# Impersonation issue after migrating from Oracle JDK 8 to Open JDK 8 in Cloudera cluster

Tags: java, hadoop, kerberos, cloudera

Recently I moved from the Oracle JDK 8 to Open JDK 8 (version: openjdk-1.8.0.242.b08) for Cloudera. Cloudera version is 5.16.2. I have Kerberos and TLS enabled. When I am using Oracle JDK the below issue doesn't occur but when I switch to Open JDK then I am getting the below error. Please note that the proxy user is already enabled from the CM -> HDFS -> configuration.

```
JobHistoryServer    
Error starting JobHistoryServer
org.apache.hadoop.yarn.exceptions.YarnRuntimeException: Error creating done directory: [hdfs://XXXX.YYY.COM:8020/user/history/done]
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.hs.HistoryFileManager.tryCreatingHistoryDirs(HistoryFileManager.java:680)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.hs.HistoryFileManager.createHistoryDirs(HistoryFileManager.java:616)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.hs.HistoryFileManager.serviceInit(HistoryFileManager.java:577)
    at org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService.init(AbstractService.java:163)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.hs.JobHistory.serviceInit(JobHistory.java:95)
    at org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService.init(AbstractService.java:163)
    at org.apache.hadoop.service.CompositeService.serviceInit(CompositeService.java:107)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.hs.JobHistoryServer.serviceInit(JobHistoryServer.java:154)
    at org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService.init(AbstractService.java:163)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.hs.JobHistoryServer.launchJobHistoryServer(JobHistoryServer.java:229)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.hs.JobHistoryServer.main(JobHistoryServer.java:239)
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(org.apache.hadoop.security.authorize.AuthorizationException): User: RZgWaGioVf@YYY.COM is not allowed to impersonate mapred/XXXX.YYY.COM@YYY.COM
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1504)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1441)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:231)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy16.getFileInfo(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.getFileInfo(ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.java:788)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:258)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:104)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy17.getFileInfo(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.getFileInfo(DFSClient.java:2168)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Hdfs.getFileStatus(Hdfs.java:133)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileContext$14.next(FileContext.java:1143)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileContext$14.next(FileContext.java:1139)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSLinkResolver.resolve(FSLinkResolver.java:90)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileContext.getFileStatus(FileContext.java:1139)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileContext$Util.exists(FileContext.java:1604)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.hs.HistoryFileManager.mkdir(HistoryFileManager.java:733)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.hs.HistoryFileManager.tryCreatingHistoryDirs(HistoryFileManager.java:663)
```

Comment: Quoting _"Hadoop and Kerberos, the Madness beyond the Gate"_ from the top of my mind >> THE HADOOP TEAM IS SCARED OF NEW VERSIONS OF JAVA

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This issue is resolved. The issue was due to the cross-realm referrals support for Kerberos ([`JDK-8215032`](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8215032)). You need to set `-Dsun.security.krb5.disableReferrals=true` property of the service or to set this is `java.security` file.

Comment: See also -> https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8239385

Answer (score 3):

This is a known bug I filed with openJDK.

"KerberosTicket client name refers wrongly to sAMAccountName in AD", Major loss of Function.

It is tracked here: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8239385

Answer (score 1):

Might be related to my problem: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openjdk-8/+bug/1861883

I also reported this to the OpenJDK bug report site (twice) but no reaction so far.

If your problem disappears after downgrading to OpenJDK 1.8.0 232 we've been hit by the same bug.